# NSSoftLinking - The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina (beta), I create a fresh macOS project in Xcode 11 (beta).

In the creation wizard I select Objective-C, and "Use XIBs".

If I run the project, I get the following console output:

```
foo_project[20548:102646] NSSoftLinking - The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' 
   can't be found in the (null) framework.

foo_project[20548:102646] Metal API Validation Enabled
```

Can anyone explain this message?

EDIT:

@vardaasen reports:

> Not the same problem but a similar message. I get the message when I
>   run:
>
> ```
> sh /opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
> ```
>
> Installing java and android studio with macports and anaconda/conda gives:
>
> ```
> java[11042:345832] NSSoftLinking - The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect based on the error message that the required functionality isn't in the OS yet (it's getting called but no one is there to answer/respond). Perhaps beta 5 will include it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems related to how FileVault security is respected? See:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_beta_4_release_notes

In part, it reads:

> • Warning: Your Secure Token might be lost if FileVault is enabled on a non-APFS formatted volume while upgrading to macOS 10.15. You might be able to work around this by disabling FileVault before upgrading to macOS 10.15, then reenabling FileVault once the upgrade has completed. (51091312)

Answer (score 1):

For me this error wasn't really the problem that lead to a crash. It read further down in the log:

```
_GSRegisterPurpleNamedPortInPrivateNamespace Couldn't register
  maccatalyst.xxx.gsEvents with the bootstrap server. 
Error: unknown error code (1100).
  This generally means that another instance of this process was 
  already running or is hung in the debugger.
```

For me the problem was solved by looking at the running processes and killing another instance of my app that was still somehow running.