# The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macos-catalina

I installed the MacOS Catalina beta and I tied to update the google chrome. But its giving the following error message

```
2019-07-22 12:10:46.071 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[1827:44902] NSSoftLinking - The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework.
KSInstallAction install script failure. Exit code: 12. Standard error output: "goobspatch: old hash mismatch: 6f3b7e392fba8665c971a110254954a86ed2e56e != 5c333879450103300e0ca50c73676b2dd9acac13\ndirpatcher.sh: couldn't create /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/75.0.3770.142/Google Chrome Framework by applying /tmp/KSInstallAction.1Lbl0BD7bQ/m/.patch/framework_75.0.3770.100_75.0.3770.142.dirpatch/Google Chrome Framework$gbs to /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/75.0.3770.100/Google Chrome Framework\n.keystone_install: dirpatcher of versioned directory failed, status 13\n".
```

Anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSSoftLinking - The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076587/nssoftlinking-the-function-slsissuppressedbyscreentime-cant-be-found-in-the)

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9409226?hl=en