# 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework

Tags: c, macos

I am using the CSFML and with the new catalina update I have this message :

```
2019-07-23 21:04:48.394 my_rpg[1383:98957] NSSoftLinking - The function 'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework.

We got a keyboard without any keys (1)

We got a keyboard without any keys (1)
```

I don't know why but I think it is the new catalina update.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: this could be a same error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076587/nssoftlinking-the-function-slsissuppressedbyscreentime-cant-be-found-in-the

Answer (score 0):

error fixed, i update macos catalina today and the message "'SLSIsSuppressedByScreenTime' can't be found in the (null) framework" is over. 
then, for the error "We got a keyboard without any keys (1)

We got a keyboard without any keys (1)"
go to SETTINGS > SAFETY > MONITORING and select your IDE.